# Which template should I start with in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ios4

My app idea allows people to see a list of items, 6 per page illustrated as icon/images. You’ll be able to switch between 1-6, 7-12,13-18 etc by swiping your finger across the screen (similar to that of the home screen within iOS), to view these batch of images/icons. If you press an Icon you view another screen with an image and some text. All the different images on the homescreen-style-page all click through to the same “template”, just with different content.

My question is, is this a view based application, window based application, or navigation based application?  Which template should I start with?

I'm not sure how to start this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing a Page Control. You can use the View Based application template to get started, or the window one if you're planning on adding the view yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a navigation controller based app with a paging scroll view for root view controller instead of table view controller.

So start with a Navigation-based Application and change the RootViewController to suit your requirements.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for taking the time to answer the question. Much appreciated! I've decided to go with Christian due to the upvotes.